# Creating custom JSON response with Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to create a custom JSON response in Jbuilder. The scheme is pretty simple:

```
json.name = @locations.name
json.description = @locations.description
```

However, I am getting a Missing Template error because I have namespaced my route and cannot use the current index.son.jbuilder. Currently, my route is setup as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
   namespace :v1 do
      resources :locations
    end
  end

  root 'locations#index'
  resources :locations
...
```

And my controller is pretty simple:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class LocationsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def index
        @locations = Location.all
      end
    end
   end
end
```

It does not currently use my index.son.jbuilder. I have attempted to create a new json file with matches the naming scheme *api.v1.index.json.jbuilder* but the error persists. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this not just a simple typo? `views/api/v1/index.json.jbuilder` - you're missing the `j` in `json`, son :)

Comment: Note that rails uses directories for "namespaced views" not dots in the file name.

Comment: Hey. Sorry it is not a typo in the actual project

Comment: I was unaware that rails uses directories in the name. Will try this thanks